# Undefined index in dropdown menu

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, undefined

I have a dropdown menu with and define it in top pages after post submitted like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD' ] == 'POST' ) {

$usertype = clean($_POST['usertype']);
$useroption = array('admin', 'author', 'public');
```

and in my form here's the code:

```
<tr>
            <td><label for="usertype">User Type</label></td>
            <td><select name="usertype" id="usertype">
                    <option disabled selected>Please choose the user right</option>
                    <?php foreach($useroption as $val): ?>
                        <option
                            value="<?php echo $val; ?>"
                            <?php echo (isset($error, $usertype) && $usertype == $val) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>
                            >
                            <?php echo ucfirst($val); ?>
                        </option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select></td>
        </tr></form>
```

but I got messages  Notice: Undefined index: usertype in E:\EasyPHP\data\localweb\projects\Gamma\add-user.php on line 20 in this my script its:

```
$usertype = clean($_POST['usertype']);
```

please help me which code or what I missed that causing this trouble

I already try remove my clean function but the result is still the same. but just in case you are wondering what my clean code then here it is:

```
function clean($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES);
    $data = str_replace(array("&lt;strong&gt;", "&lt;/strong&gt;"), array("<strong>", "</strong>"), $data);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, you send something via `POST` in `usertype`? Check for it with `print_r($_POST);` or `print_r($_REQUEST);`.

Comment: ok i'll try to print it

Comment: Sorry made a typo. ;)

Comment: @DOCASAREL you are right, it's not being sent. but why? meanwhile the other field didn't give this kind of error?

Comment: Either you do not set it up properly via  AJAX or the `form` properties are wrong. Could you post it here? What do you mean with "other field"?

Comment: i have couple of field that also empty like this:

 $firstname= clean($_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname= clean($_POST['lastname']);
    $username = clean($_POST['username']);
    $email = clean($_POST['email']);

Comment: but it doesn't make undefined index

Comment: Empty is not undefined. ;)

Comment: but those field is sent together with usertype, how come only usertype that give this kind of error?

Comment: You said `usertype` is not being sent. Check for this.

Comment: i think it's because of this : <option disabled selected>Please choose the user right</option> if i select the other it's fine. have solution for this?

Comment: You should not make it an option, just a label or something. It is because it is `disabled` I guess...

Answer (score 1):

there is not any **usertype** index in `$_POST[]` so try a check for

```
$usertype = (isset($_POST['usertype']) ? clean($_POST['usertype']) :'');
```

Comment: it work, but why? meanwhile the other is not give that problems even it's empty?

Comment: check your posting data and form field name is correct print_r($_POST)

Comment: yeah i already did it, it's not being sent? is it something that i missed here?

Answer (score 0):

change option into this:

```
            <option selected >Please choose the user right</option>
```